# C# issues with closing the form

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

I have been experiencing problems with closing the Log In form when I have switched to 2nd form on successful Log In. I tried `.close` and `.dispose`, but the Log in Form wouldn't close. Following is my code.

```
namespace Lead_Management_Pro
{
    public partial class FrmLogin : Form
    {
        Form1 mainform;
        public FrmLogin()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            FrmLogin frm = new FrmLogin();
            mainform = new Form1();
            string[] v;

            OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection("File Name=E:\\Vivek\\License Manager\\License Manager\\login.udl");

            try
            {
                conn.Open();

                string query = "EXEC dbo.checkuser '" + username.Text+ "', '" + password.Text+"'";
                OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, conn);
                string s = Convert.ToString(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
                v= s.Split('|');
                if (v[0]=="0")
                {

                    frm.Close();
                    mainform.ShowDialog();
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Please enter correct user credentials and try again");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }

            conn.Close();
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Please help me to rectify the issue.

Comment: Could u edit your post with the given error ?

Comment: @NicolasPierre Thanks for replying.I am not getting any errors as such.But the Log In form is not closing when I switch to main form.

frm.close() is not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`frm.Close()` closes the instance you are making. 
you should use `this.Close();` like the one you did in `button2_Click` event

**Update 2**

`FrmLogin` is your startup form. Try hiding it:

```
if (v[0]=="0")
{
    mainform.Show();
    this.Hide();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for replying.this.close is closing both the forms ie Login and the main form

Comment: @user2614235 try `mainform.Show; this.Close();`

Comment: @user2614235 `FrmLogin` is your startup form. Try hiding it `this.Hide();`

Comment: I even tried using this.Hide().But don't whats happening.The Log in Form is not closing.

Comment: Hey I used this.Hide() now its working fine :) ..Thanks for helping

Comment: @user2614235 I guess you were trying to hide the instance. You don't need to use the instance of the form you are in. welx :)

Comment: this.close() is closing both the forms when I use

if (v[0]=="0")
{
    mainform.Show();
    this.close();
}

Comment: @user2614235 Yeah. You can't close your startup form.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue in one of my projects. The problem is that if you open your login form as your first form, it's viewed as the main form, and when you close it, the program starts shutting down because you closed your main form.

What you need to do is open your login form from the context of your Form1 main form, instead of opening your main form from the context of your login form.

in pseudocode:

```
public Form1(){
    if(not logged in)
    {
        FrmLogin login = new FrmLogin();
        login.ShowDialog();//This blocks the further execution of the Form1 constructor until you're out of the window
    }
    InitializeCompent();
}
```

Handle your login procedure in your Login form and close the form in there once you're logged in. It will automatically continue on to the rest of your Form1 constructor and open it through there. You might want to have a check after executing your login whether you're actually logged in, and shut down if you're not.